# В какой жизненный цикл переходит не активный фрагмент

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, activity-life-cycle

У меня есть одно активити и много фрагментов, которые подставляются туда. Так вот на каком жизненном цикле останавливается фрагмент, на который наложили другой фрагмент?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

если он сохраняется в стэке - `onPause`.
если нет (вызываете `popbackstack`) - `onDestroy`.

но сразу стоит отметить, что нахождение в состоянии onPause **НЕ** гарантирует, что сама ОС не прибьет Фрагмент.
в таких случаях, ОС пересоздает Фрагмент. а данные, которые были в нем, вытягиваются либо из `bundle` либо из `ViewModel`